# Response is getting null from controller to $http.get response

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I am working on a maven project using hibernate as instance of H2 database implementation and my project is getting successfully built

However while I am running my application I am getting SQL syntax error or SQLGRAMMER exception stating

> "your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'function
>   function1_ on function0_.function_id=function1_.id where
>   function0_.rol' at line 1"

Here is my Java code :

```
private AuthenticationResult checkAccoutInAzureAD(String username, String password) {
    AuthenticationContext context = null;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;

    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext(appConfiguration.getAd_url1(), false, service);
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                appConfiguration.getAd_url2(), appConfiguration.getAd_id(), username, password, 
                null);

        System.out.println("roopam checking second URL"+future);
        result = future.get();
        System.out.println("result"+result);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("InterruptedException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("ExecutionException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("MalformedURLException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    if (result == null) {
        System.out.println("Account is not existing)");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Access Token : " + result.getAccessToken() );
        System.out.println("Refresh Token : " + result.getRefreshToken() );

    }
    return result;
}
```

And my complete stack trace:

```
    Jun 18, 2019 9:34:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.41


 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: login.microsoftonline.com
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.readResponseFromConnection(HttpHelper.java:86)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.getResponse(HttpHelper.java:182)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeGetRequest(HttpHelper.java:158)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.HttpHelper.executeHttpGet(HttpHelper.java:59)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.UserDiscoveryRequest.execute(UserDiscoveryRequest.java:40)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.processPasswordGrant(AuthenticationContext.java:798)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext.access$000(AuthenticationContext.java:64)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:140)
        at com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext$1.call(AuthenticationContext.java:130)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
    Account is not existing)
    2019-06-18 21:35:13.768  INFO 15208 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.amdocs.rest.AuthenticationController   : No records in Azure AD; username (superadmin)
    2019-06-18 21:35:13.769  INFO 15208 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.amdocs.rest.AuthenticationController   : Pass Token (123)
    2019-06-18 21:35:14.074  INFO 15208 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
    2019-06-18 21:35:15.392  WARN 15208 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
    2019-06-18 21:35:15.392 ERROR 15208 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'function function1_ on function0_.function_id=function1_.id where function0_.rol' at line 1
    2019-06-18 21:35:15.480 ERROR 15208 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/auth/login] due to exception [could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet]

    org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:126) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at com.amdocs.rest.AuthenticationController.createAuthenticationToken(AuthenticationController.java:121) ~[classes/:IOI]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.41]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.41]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
    Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488) ~[spring-orm-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.findByUsername(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.amdocs.service.impl.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:22) ~[classes/:IOI]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114) ~[spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        ... 71 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:739) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:924) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:54) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:208) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.8.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        ... 82 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'function function1_ on function0_.function_id=function1_.id where function0_.rol' at line 1
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
```

Comment: Hi Roopam! Please Add your java code which is causing this exception to the post, for getting answers that will resolve your issue

Comment: It would be better if this is added to post :)

Comment: Added......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function` is a SQL keyword. Choose another name for your table.